# div section persistently on top of other div section, not sure why

Tags: html, css, divide

I'm trying to get the "learn" div section below the text section (before the actual footer) but for some reason, when I added the picture (which I floated to be next to the right of text), the "learn" div is now on top of the text section. The image/text are part of the same div container.

Is there anything I can do to rectify that?

Thanks

```css
.introduction img{
  float: right;
}

.introduction p{
  width:60%;
  text-align:center;
  margin:0 auto;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size:16px;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

/********* Footer with links ************/
.footerwrapper {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  background-color: #333;
  position: absolute;
}

.contentcontainer {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.footitle p {
  text-align:left;
  color: #EEEEEE;
}

.twocols {
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 5px;
}

.twocolsblock1 .twocolsblock2 {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 31%;
  align-items: center;
}

.lessonlinkblurb.footer {
  color: #E5E5E5;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 21px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="introduction">
    <img src="images/Chokwe_People.jpg" alt="Chokwe Language in Africa" width="300" height="300">
    <p>
        KUCHI is one of the most common words you will hear spoken throughout the Chokwe world. This is the simplest greeting, and is often the first word learned by those who have an interest in the language.

    </p>
</div>
<div class="footerwrapper">
    <div class="contentcontainer">
        <h3 class="footitle">
        <p id="learn">Learn Chokwe</p>
        <div class="twocols">
            <div class="twocolsblock1">

                <a href="/greetings.html" class="lessonlink w-inline-block">
                    <div class="lessonlinktitle footer">Greetings</div>
                    <div class="lessonlinkblurb footer">How to greet and some basic phrases in Chokwe</div>
                </a>

                <a href="/intro.html" class="lessonlink w-inline-block">
                    <div class="lessonlinktitle footer">Introductions</div>
                    <div class="lessonlinkblurb footer">How to introduce yourself and your family in Chokwe</div>
                </a>

                <a href="/scenarios.html" class="lessonlink w-inline-block">
                    <div class="lessonlinktitle footer">Scenarios</div>
                    <div class="lessonlinkblurb footer">Learn what to say in certain scenarios in Chokwe</div>
                </a>

                <a href="/timenumbers.html" class="lessonlink w-inline-block">
                    <div class="lessonlinktitle footer">Time and time concepts</div>
                    <div class="lessonlinkblurb footer">How say late, early and days of the week, months of the year in Chokwe</div>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="twocolsblock2">
                <a href="/learn-italian/question-words" class="lessonlink w-inline-block">
                    <div class="lessonlinktitle footer">Question words</div>
                    <div class="lessonlinkblurb footer">Who? What? When? Where? Why? How? How much? How many? <br>How to ask questions in Chokwe</div>
                </a>

                <a href="/verbs.html" class="lessonlink w-inline-block">
                    <div class="lessonlinktitle footer">Important Verbs</div>
                    <div class="lessonlinkblurb footer">To be, To Have, To Do, To Say, To Go, To Know, To Want, To Can & To Use. <br> How to use verbs in Chowke</div>
                </a>

                <a href="/proverbs" class="lessonlink w-inline-block">
                    <div class="lessonlinktitle footer">Proverbs</div>
                    <div class="lessonlinkblurb footer">Learn some important sayings and proverbs in Chokwe</div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you put your code in a snippet so we can see the problem.

Comment: lose the absolute positioning. you want it to be placed relative to your content (the default way)

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by  `"learn" div section`. Which `div` are you are trying to target.

Comment: Hey @ManasKhandelwal, I mean I want the <div class="footerwrapper"> to be below the  <div class="introduction"> div. The way it is, the footerwrapper div somehow goes on top of the introduction div and im not sure why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, when you use the style `position: absolute` and `float`, the element will be removed from the normal flow of the page. This makes your `div.introduction img` and `div.introduction p` flow to be removed thus making the next element which is `div.footerwrapper` to move up relative to it's parent location

So you can use the solution from [Manas Khandelwal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65702009/2674662) by using `clear` which will return the flow of the element after the element with `float` style

Or you can remove the `float: left;` from the `div.introduction p` so it will take up the space left by `div.introduction img`, and also remove the `position: absolute;` from `div.footerwrapper` because it's not needed in the flow

```css
.introduction img{
  float: right;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.introduction p{
  text-align:right;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size:16px;
}

/********* Footer with links ************/
.footerwrapper {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  background-color: #333;
}

.contentcontainer {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.footitle p {
  text-align:left;
  color: #EEEEEE;
}

.twocols {
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 5px;
}

.twocolsblock1 .twocolsblock2 {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 31%;
  align-items: center;
}

.lessonlinkblurb.footer {
  color: #E5E5E5;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 21px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="introduction">
    <img src="images/Chokwe_People.jpg" alt="Chokwe Language in Africa" width="300" height="100">
    <p>
        KUCHI is one of the most common words you will hear spoken throughout the Chokwe world. This is the simplest greeting, and is often the first word learned by those who have an interest in the language. KUCHI is one of the most common words you will hear spoken throughout the Chokwe world. This is the simplest greeting, and is often the first word learned by those who have an interest in the language.

    </p>
</div>
<div class="footerwrapper">
    <div class="contentcontainer">
        <h3 class="footitle">
        <p id="learn">Learn Chokwe</p>
        <div class="twocols">
            <div class="twocolsblock1">

                <a href="/greetings.html" class="lessonlink w-inline-block">
                    <div class="lessonlinktitle footer">Greetings</div>
                    <div class="lessonlinkblurb footer">How to greet and some basic phrases in Chokwe</div>
                </a>

                <a href="/intro.html" class="lessonlink w-inline-block">
                    <div class="lessonlinktitle footer">Introductions</div>
                    <div class="lessonlinkblurb footer">How to introduce yourself and your family in Chokwe</div>
                </a>

                <a href="/scenarios.html" class="lessonlink w-inline-block">
                    <div class="lessonlinktitle footer">Scenarios</div>
                    <div class="lessonlinkblurb footer">Learn what to say in certain scenarios in Chokwe</div>
                </a>

                <a href="/timenumbers.html" class="lessonlink w-inline-block">
                    <div class="lessonlinktitle footer">Time and time concepts</div>
                    <div class="lessonlinkblurb footer">How say late, early and days of the week, months of the year in Chokwe</div>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="twocolsblock2">
                <a href="/learn-italian/question-words" class="lessonlink w-inline-block">
                    <div class="lessonlinktitle footer">Question words</div>
                    <div class="lessonlinkblurb footer">Who? What? When? Where? Why? How? How much? How many? <br>How to ask questions in Chokwe</div>
                </a>

                <a href="/verbs.html" class="lessonlink w-inline-block">
                    <div class="lessonlinktitle footer">Important Verbs</div>
                    <div class="lessonlinkblurb footer">To be, To Have, To Do, To Say, To Go, To Know, To Want, To Can & To Use. <br> How to use verbs in Chowke</div>
                </a>

                <a href="/proverbs" class="lessonlink w-inline-block">
                    <div class="lessonlinktitle footer">Proverbs</div>
                    <div class="lessonlinkblurb footer">Learn some important sayings and proverbs in Chokwe</div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*Notes: I also removed the `width` from `div.introduction.p` and add `margin` to `div.introduction img` to make some space between the `p` and `img`, because when the `img` is using `float: right`, the `inline element` will wrap around it

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove `position: absolute;` from the div `.footerwrapper`.
2. Add a class of any name to the `.introduction` div and apply these properties, like this

```
.clearfix:after  {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```
<div class="introduction clearfix">
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/QWKZoqJ